# Regression Model in R

Tags: r, regression

I want to run a regression model on a dichotomous variable in R. For example, in my data I have a variable that illustrates state failure, "1"= state failure "2" = no state failure. My dependent variable is the number of newly formed terrorist groups per country year coded from 0-11. How would I go about running a regression with the state failure variable? Would I have to create dummy variables if my data is already coded numerically, if so what would be the code to do this? Anything will help, thank you.

Comment: `glm(I(failure == '1') ~ factor(group), data = my_data, family = 'binomial')` or similar. you do not need to explicitly create the dummy coding, if a variable is a factor, `model.matrix` will do that for you, for example, `model.matrix(~ factor(group), data = my_data)` to see what the default is. see `?model.matrix` for more details

Comment: Have you tried searching the internet for "logistic regression in R"?

Comment: Yes, I don't think I can use a logit regression because my dependent variable (y) is not coded 0 and 1, it is a continuous variable. My independent variable is dichotomous.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create dummy variables. Your outcome variable is ordinal, but with 12 possible values, this is often simply treated as numeric, so I would start with `lm(outcome ~ var)` and inspect the residuals to assess whether this is a reasonable treatment. An alternative would be ordinal regression, such as `MASS::polr()`